# Simply connected reduced suspension on path connected X

Tags: algebraic-topology

If X is path connected how may i show that the reduced Suspension $\Sigma $ X is then simply connected. I cannot seem to picture this construction

Comment: Do you know the seifert can kampen theorem?

Comment: Whilst I thought it was true immediately by the Freudenthal suspension theorem, there are a serious of posts by Tom Goodwillie http://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg26, http://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg27, http://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg28 that suggests it might not (always be true). Although I can't see any flaw in the argument provided below...

Comment: @JuanS: I haven't read the posts in detail, but in the first one the counterexample he produces involved the Hawaiian earring which does not satisfy the hypotheses of Freudenthal's suspension theorem.

Answer (score 6):

An overkilling answer could be the following: The [Freudenthal suspension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_suspension_theorem) tells us that, if $X$ is $n$-connected, then the natural morphism

$$
\pi_k(X) \longrightarrow \pi_{k+1}(\Sigma X)
$$

is an isomorphism for $k\leq 2n$. Particularly, for $n=0$, we have an isomorphism $\pi_1(\Sigma X) = 1$.

But, if you want to "picture" the situation, take a look at this [suspension drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_%28topology%29), and use the [Seifert-van Kampen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem), as mland points you. Particularly, look at Wikipedia's computation of $\pi_1(S^2)$.

Comment: Well, this doesn't say why $\pi_0(\Sigma X)=0$ :) (which can be seen just from the definition of $\Sigma X$).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brief outline:

Note that $\Sigma X = X \times I / ( X \times \partial I \cup \{x_0\} \times I )$, where $x_0$ is assumed to be the base point of $X$ and $\partial I = \{0,1\}$.

Taking any loop $f: [0,1] \to \Sigma X$, one can define the following homotopy:
$$
H(x, t) = [(f(x), 1-t)]
$$
where for any $\alpha \in X \times I$, $[\alpha]$ denotes its equivalence class in $\Sigma X$.

Use the universal property of quotient spaces to show that this map is continuous, and check that it is also a homotopy. This will show that every loop is homotopic to the constant loop, and thus, $\pi_1(X) = 0$.

As for connectedness of $\Sigma X$, just note that $X$ is connected, so $X \times I$ is connected, and quotients of connected spaces are connected, therefore $\Sigma X$ is connected.