# An example that Freudenthal Suspension Theorem does't apply.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $\sum X$ be the reduce suspension of $X$.

Freudenthal Suspension Theorem:  X is nondegenerately based and (n−1)-connected, where n ≥ 1. Then $\sum: \pi_q(X) \to \pi_q(\sum X)$ is a bijection if $q < 2n−1$ and a surjection if $q = 2n − 1$.

Note: nondegenerately based means the inclusion of the based point $\ast \hookrightarrow X $ is a cofibration.

We know that based on Freudenthal Suspension Theorem, for nondegenerately based path connected space X, $\sum X$ is simply connected.

My question:

Is there any example such that:
X is path connected but not nondegenerately based and $\sum X$ is not simply connected.

Comment: As pointed out in comments at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195076/simply-connected-reduced-suspension-on-path-connected-x, Tom Goodwillie described an example: the unreduced cone on the set $\{0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ...\}$. See https://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg26, https://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg27, and https://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg28.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri The OP looks for a path connected $X$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, and the cone on that set is path connected.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I should have read more carefully ;-) Perhaps you should give an official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments at math.stackexchange.com/questions/195076/…, Tom Goodwillie described an example: let $X$ be the unreduced cone $CZ$ on the set $Z=\{ 0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...\}$. See lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg26, lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg27, and lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg28.